# Get average value for every N tuples in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, quantile

Assuming I have a table with two columns **CUSTTYPE** and **AMOUNT**. I want to add a third column **NTILE** which I can then group on and use to get my averages, something like below:

```
CUSTTYPE | AMOUNT  | NTILE
----------+---------+----------
 RETAIL   |   78.00 |   1
 RETAIL   |  234.00 |   1
 RETAIL   |  249.00 |   1
 RETAIL   |  278.00 |   2
 RETAIL   |  392.00 |   2
 RETAIL   |  498.00 |   2
 RETAIL   |  500.00 |   3
 RETAIL   |  738.00 |   3
 RETAIL   | 1250.00 |   3
 RETAIL   | 2029.00 |   4
 RETAIL   | 2393.00 |   4
 RETAIL   | 3933.00 |   4
```

Essentially, I am trying to take the average of every n terms (here, n=3):

```
CUSTTYPE | AMOUNT  | NTILE
----------+---------+----------
 RETAIL   | 187.00 |   1
 RETAIL   | 389.33 |   2
 RETAIL   | 829.33 |   3
 RETAIL   | 2785.0 |   4
```

From the Pig reference [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/Over.html), it seems this could be achieved using `Over()` but I could not find an example of how this could be done. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rank every record of your data using `RANK` operator:

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#rank

like this:

```
A = LOAD 'path' AS (schema);
B = RANK A;
```

and then divide each rank by 3:

```
C = FOREACH B generate ($0 + 1) / 3 as NTILE, CUSTTYPE, AMOUNT;
```